# git reset --hard error: Could not parse object

Tags: git, terminal, osx-mavericks

This is not the first time I am doing a hard reset on my repo but this time, I am getting an error. I am working on an iOS Project. I am doing the reset from terminal. How do I fix the fatal error

```
fatal: Could not parse object 'e88056ac5d58fb0bbd23d3fe929eac01712d964'
```

Comment: What command did you run, exactly? Just `git reset --hard`?

Comment: What steps did you originally do that caused your repo to get into an unhappy state?

Comment: just `git reset --hard`. I am the only one working on my repo but I am using two computers. It's been a while since I used one of the computers so I know whatever it has is obsolete. That's all.

Comment: What do `git cat-file -t e88056ac5d58fb0bbd23d3fe929eac01712d964`, `git rev-parse HEAD`, and `git ls-tree HEAD` return?

Comment: Have you tried git gc to clean up the git repo?

Answer (score 14):

I have same problem and fixed.

> This problem occurs when there have been changes like force-pushes to
>   a git repo which is referenced in a Gemfile.
>
> The solution is is to comment that gem line in Gemfile, run bundle,
>   uncomment it and bundle again. Then the Gemfile.lock will reference a
>   valid git revision.

Found in this link https://semaphoreci.com/docs/fail-could-not-parse-object.html

Answer (score 12):

For me, the problem was that on my local machine I needed to pull the latest version of my branch, merge, and commit. Then the `git reset --hard {hash}` worked on the server I was running the command on.

Comment: Do you mean `git reset --hard {hash}`?

Comment: @SolomonUcko Thanks! I fixed it.

Answer (score 12):

Try updating your local repo with

```
git fetch
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a git shallow clone (clone with command: `git clone --depth=1 git@github.com:foo/bar.git`), this might be the problem.

Try this out:

```sh
git fetch --unshallow
```

and then `git reset` may be working.

Ref:

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it with

```
$ git remote add origin <repo_link>
$ git fetch
$ git reset --hard <commit_id>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: silly stupid bot

Answer (score 2):

What git is telling you is that commit SHA could not be found in the repository so you need to either:

1. Ensure you have the latest version of the repository by fetching as other answers have suggested, or
2. Double check **you're in the right local folder**

Maybe everyone here is smarter than me but it took me some time to realize that I wasn't even in the right git folder...

Answer (score 1):

May be you should push your code to remote directory first and then execute the command,

```
git reset --hard <commit_id>
```

Finally the bug will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

First update external branch 
   git remote update
Then 
   git reset --hard

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a five year old question with five other existing answers it is very helpful to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this was caused by the remote git repository merging the branch, so you need to find the new commit_id after the merge and try again.